# Stretch a button in a collapsed navbar (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want "Sign in" button to be like this.

[image]

But i get this.

[image]

What's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- home, scheduler, actions-->
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign in</a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the Button CSS code as well.

Comment: I did not use CSS, only Bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you'll have to do this yourself with CSS. You could use the btn-block class but it will adversely alter your `navbar` at widths above 768px.

See Example 1.

But if you adjust your navbar structure and add another ul and place the button inside of it, you can use `btn-block` See Example 2.
See working Snippet.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .btn.btn-wide {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right btn-wide"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign in</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

See Example 2.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign in</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: adding btn-lg

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <!-- home, scheduler, actions-->
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="container navbar-btn btn btn-default btn-lg navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign in</a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. It just increased the button a bit.

Comment: try now adding class="container"... I have updated the code now

Answer (score 0):

Below are the updated code. Add a `btn-block` class along the existing class.

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default navbar-right btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Sign in</a>
```